# WPF Composition/Agregation

Tags: wpf, composition

I'm looking for documentation regarding WPF best practice for Compositing and agregating the user interface in a large project.

I'm comming from a visual Inheriance world using Delphi and Winform. And I'm now try to replicate that kind of pattern well in fact reusability of those UI elements.

I'm open to suggestion and reading.

Comment: The same question is also here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2588318/how-to-design-parts-of-the-application-in-xaml-and-how-to-reusing-it-then

Answer (score 0):

The Composite Application Guidance (sometimes called "Prism") is appropriate, especially if the application has a lot of moving parts developed by different teams.

We've been using this for a while and while the patterns aren't very similar to what you've experienced with Delphi, they are very good and the documentation is excellent.  The functionality you get is pretty amazing.

More info here: [Composite Application Guidance on Codeplex](http://www.codeplex.com/CompositeWPF)