# How to organize architecture WPF project?

Tags: c#, wpf, architecture

In my WPF project i want to have only one Window - MainWindow and UserControls as working part. I have some little different applications in one, and want to make navigation on top of my MainWindow as buttons. And little applications as UserControl. In MainWindow - grid with Big Empty Zone - which use to keep and run work. But, i want to navigate to other userControl from another. (probably do not understand :()

How organize architecture WPF project that: one main window and many usercontrols which places in mainwindow and replace each other in turn. and there is the possibility of navigating from another usercontrol to another.

May be it's MVVM, but i don't understand how this pattern can help me.

Comment: If anyone has a pointer to a good introduction of MVVM (i.e. one that goes beyond trivial examples) a link would be appreciated.

Comment: @Richard : http://karlshifflett.wordpress.com/2010/05/09/stuff-wpf-line-of-business-using-mvvm-video-tutorial/

Answer (score 3):

You might be interested in the **ViewModel** sample application of the **[WPF Application Framework (WAF)](http://waf.codeplex.com)** project.

Answer (score 1):

My best source is [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/Cinch.aspx). Its the place that got me started on my journey to MVVM. Full working examples and workable solutions.

Answer (score 0):

- http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/Wikipage - I was looking for it in past and it's the only thing I've found so far.
- [How to design parts of the application in XAML and how to reusing it then?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2588318/how-to-design-parts-of-the-application-in-xaml-and-how-to-reusing-it-then)