# C# make each panel in a separate view

Tags: c#, panel

I would like to know how I could possibly modulate my views in an application. Let me explain.

Instead of building my view and adding all the components in one screen. I want to say put each panel in its own class / form and then have a main form where I can add and remove these 'modular' panels.

Is this possible and how would I go about doing it?

Comment: If you're using WPF check out PRISM http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg406140.aspx

Comment: related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138062/wpf-composition-agregation

Comment: Yes, it is possible. If you want ot use winforms - create UserControl(s) and then put them in a Container (TableLayoutPanel or SplitContainer or Panel or etc.) or put the UserControl directly to the Form Controls collection.

Comment: @Stephen im not sure if I am using WPF. I am new to c# so would you recommend that I use it?

Comment: I think we need a clarification - do you want to put your views into separate assemblies and load them on the fly in your application (PRISM/MEF) or you want UserControls that are views that can be added / removed on the fly to a control's container?

Comment: @pasty I think the second option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Windows Forms there is the concept of an empty component called UserControl, that can be freely designed and added at any time to another component or form container. UserControls are used very often in order to create flexible and exchangable UI. You can create a [UserControl item](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.usercontrol.aspx) in Visual Studio like this:

[image: Add new UserControl to an existing project]

Name the new control:

[image: Naming new control and adding it]

After that you can design your UI control:

[image: Design control]

When your are done with the design, compile your project/solution and go to the form where you want to add your newly designed control. In the toolbar panel you will see your new UserControl, which can be added to the form with drag & drop (with the mouse):

[image: Add new user control to the form]

You can create as many UserControls as you want and add/remove them to/from your form.

All of this steps can be done completely in the code. In order to create new view of this kind, you need to create a new class that inherits the predefined UserControl class:

```
public class EditorUserControl : UserControl
{
}
```

Every Control element has a [ControlsCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.aspx) that holds/contains components of type Control that are *drawn* when the UI is shown. In order to add your new control to the main panel you need to add it to the controls collection:

```
public partial class EditorUserControl : UserControl
{
    public EditorUserControl()
    {
        var button = new Button();
        button.Text = "Import";
        this.Controls.Add(button);
    }
}
```

Note, that when adding components manually, you are responsible for sizing and position them. Predefined layout panels can help you here:

- [TableLayoutPanel - layout with cells](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.aspx)
- [SplitPanel - horizontal or vertical predefined resizable panels](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.splitcontainer.aspx)
- etc.

Now all that left is to add the new user control to the main form just like you added the UI elements to your own control:

```
var simpleEditor = new EditorUserControl();
simpleEditor.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
this.Controls.Add(simpleEditor);
```

You can adjust the UI control settings through its predefined properties.

You can mix predefined containers and UserControls in order to achieve the desired UI:

[image: mixed UI]

There are a lot of good beginners tutorials for C# and VS and .NET:

- [Channel9 tutorials](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/C-Sharp-Fundamentals-Development-for-Absolute-Beginners)
- [MSDN Visual Studio UI tutorials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd492171.aspx)
- [Composite UserControl tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a6h7e207%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)
- [Developing with Windows Forms Documentation and Examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ettb6e2a%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely possible. I will use WinForms but there are similar ways in WPF such as frames.

In WinForms you can create a new User Control for each 'modular' panel which will automatically create `.cs` and `.designer.cs` files just like in a normal `Form`. You can then add logic and functionality to the panels as if they were forms themselves. All that would then remain is to add the logic to the form to load the default panel on startup and think of ways of how other panels can be brought into view (e.g. a next button or having a panel on each tab in a tab control). Showing a panel in a form (or any other user control for that matter) is achieved by creating an instance of your desired panel and adding it to you form/control's `Controls` property like so:

```
 public Form1()
 {
     InitializeComponent();
     MyPanel panel = new MyPanel();
     this.Controls.Add(panel);
 }
```